# Running DPDK Load-Balancer Sample Application

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, intel, dpdk

I am using DPDK 1.7 and have followed all steps mentioned in the 'Quick-Start Guide' and 'Running Sample Application' documents to compile and execute the sample application called 'load_balancer'.

Load_balancer application contains certain I/O cores dealing with packet i/o and worker cores dealing with packet processing. My packet processing cores are not getting all the packets however i/o cores do get all the packets.

Its a complex application and uses a lot of RTE API's. Any ideas on what I should be looking into to resolve the packet processing issue ?

I have tried this on kernel version 3.2 and 3.13 with same results.

Help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a flow affinity issue. The load balancing position(default byte offset: 29) in the load balancer application only seems to handle IPv4/IPv6 packets. I had the same problem with UDP packets.

Consider using the Hash Library to generate packet hashes in your I/O RX cores and then using the hash to select the correct worker lcore to forward your packet.

Ch18:
http://dpdk.org/doc/intel/dpdk-prog-guide-1.7.0.pdf